# Array of associative arrays bash

Tags: bash, scripting

Is there a way to make an array of dictionary like in python for bash?

I want to have to keep track of multiple associative arrays in bash. Is this possible?

I am reading in from a file and each line(separated by a certain character) represents different properties.

Comment: Everything is possible if you provide a concrete problem with some examples.

Comment: When you start trying to build complicated data structures, it's time to move to a different language.

Answer (score 1):

You can trivially simulate nested associative arrays in flat ones by combining their keys:

```
declare -A array

set_value() { array[$1:$2]=$3; }
get_value() { echo "${array[$1:$2]}"; }

set_value english name "Name"
set_value fremch name "Nom"

get_value english name
```

This simple example uses `arrayname:keyname` as key. If your array or key names can contain colons, you can choose another delimiter, or add appropriate escaping.

Comment: This simulates using tuples for keys (`array[english,name]`) rather than nested arrays (`array[english][name]`). You can't, for example, easily retrieve the array `array[english]`.